# map_dfr converting data frame input to column

Tags: r, dataframe, purrr

I'm trying to use the following function to iterate through a dataframe and return the counts from each row:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
row_freq <- function(df_input,row_input){
  print(df_input)
  vec <- unlist(df_input %>% 
                  select(-1) %>% 
                  slice(row_input), use.names = FALSE)
  r <- data.frame(table(vec)) %>% 
    pivot_wider(values_from = Freq, names_from = vec)
  return(r)
}
```

This works fine if I use a single row from the dataframe:

```
sample_df <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,4,5), obs1 = c("A","A","B","B","B"),
                        obs2 = c("B","B","C","D","D"), obs3 = c("A","B","A","D","A"))
row_freq(sample_df, 1)

  id obs1 obs2 obs3
1  1    A    B    A
2  2    A    B    B
3  3    B    C    A
4  4    B    D    D
5  5    B    D    A
# A tibble: 1 × 2
      A     B
  <int> <int>
1     2     1
```

But when iterating over rows using `purrr::map_dfr`, it seems to reduce `df_input` to only the `id` column instead of using the entire dataframe as the argument, which I found quite strange:

```
purrr::map_dfr(sample_df, row_freq, 1:5)
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
 Error in UseMethod("select") : 
no applicable method for 'select' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"
```

I'm looking for help with regards to 1) why this is happening, 2) how to fix it, and 3) any alternative approaches or functions that may already perform what I'm trying to do in a more efficient manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the order of the arguments correctly if we are not passing with named arguments

```
purrr::map_dfr(1:5, ~ row_freq(sample_df, .x))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 5 × 4
      A     B     C     D
  <int> <int> <int> <int>
1     2     1    NA    NA
2     1     2    NA    NA
3     1     1     1    NA
4    NA     1    NA     2
5     1     1    NA     1
```

Or use a named argument

```
purrr::map_dfr(df_input = sample_df, .f = row_freq, .x = 1:5)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 5 × 4
      A     B     C     D
  <int> <int> <int> <int>
1     2     1    NA    NA
2     1     2    NA    NA
3     1     1     1    NA
4    NA     1    NA     2
5     1     1    NA     1
```

---

The reason is that `map` first argument is `.x`

> map(.x, .f, ...)

and if we are providing the 'sample_df' as the argument, it takes the `.x` as `sample_df` and loops over the columns of the data (as data.frame/tibble/data.table - unit is column as these are `list` with additional attributes)